# How to use GIMIC for "line integral convolution on a surface" in ParaView?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-chemistry, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am using **GIMIC** for evaluating DFT-calculations of aromatic compounds and visualizing magnetically induced aromatic ring currents. There is a nice way of visualizing them via a so called stream line plot, but I have to do it in another way. In the GIMIC docs (https://gimic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interpretation.html) there is a kind of visualization, which I have seen in different papers. This is the exact type of visualization I need to do and the authors call it "**line integral convolution on a surface**" and on the website (see link) there is the corresponding figure.

Unfortunately there is no explanation whatsoever how to create this plot in the recommended program *ParaView*.

Does anyone know how to create this kind of plot ? Any help is heavily appreciated.

Comment: I have asked the GIMIC authors to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the repo, we have the Paraview state file called 3D-LIC.pvsm

https://github.com/qmcurrents/gimic/tree/master/tools/Visualization

You need to download it, open it with Paraview and choose the vti and cml files from your calculation instead of the default paths.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: That worked for me, thank you very much !

Comment: I'm glad to hear, don't hesitate to ask us for help any time.